# Counting how many comments and how they are distributed in VBA code?

Tags: vba, excel

I am looking to create some metrics about the quality of the VBA code I am writing, through different ratios of the actual code written and comment lines written.

Ideally I am looking for a VBA script/function to detect the comment lines in Macro Enabled workbooks and Excel add-ins and being able to differentiate where the comments and code are written e.g. have the comment to code ratio for each module and form in a project.

Below is the code I have so far, but I only managed to found how to give the total count of the lines and the count for the declaration lines. Is there something similar for comments?

```
Public Sub moduleInfo()
   Dim objModule As Object
   For Each objModule In Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents
       With objModule
           Debug.Print .Name, .CodeModule.CountOfLines, .CodeModule.CountOfDeclarationLines
       End With
   Next objModule
End Sub
```

Comment: Could you please explain it with more details and it would be great if you share the code what you have tried so far

Comment: @Linga Apologies I am new to asking questions. I have added what I have so far :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can check the existence of the character `'` to spot a comment line. The comment ,ight occur anywhere in the code, such as after the instruction (you can easily modify the code if you want to count only lines that are purely comments). You can also count blank lines, because the `CountOfLines` property includes these.

```
Public Sub moduleInfo()
  Dim comp As VBComponent, m As CodeModule
  Debug.Print "Module", , "Lines", "Declarations", "Blanks", "Comments"

  For Each comp In Application.VBE.ActiveVBProject.VBComponents
    Set m = comp.CodeModule

    Dim comments As Integer, blanks As Integer, i As Integer, line As String
    For i = 1 To m.CountOfLines
        line = Trim(m.Lines(i, 1))
        If Len(line) = 0 Then
          blanks = blanks + 1
        ElseIf InStr(line, Chr(39)) Then
          comments = comments + 1
        End If
    Next
    Debug.Print m.Name, , m.CountOfLines, m.CountOfDeclarationLines, blanks, comments
  Next
End Sub
```

Comment: What if it contains a line like `Debug.Print "You can't count comments so easily"`?

Comment: @JohnColeman yeah, that is true, but this snippet is just an "starter". More checks can be done on each line. Of course, analyzing code quality is a much more difficult task, it cannot be aborded with such simplicity anyway :)

Comment: Single quotes embedded inside double quotes might be too rare to worry  about. On the other hand, scanning the line and only counting a single quote mark as a comment indicator if there is an even number of double quotes to the left should be (I think) an adequate fix. +1 if you tweak the code to handle it.

Comment: (I ended up upvoting it anyway, even without the tweak, since it is fairly useful as it stands).

Comment: @JohnColeman Thanks :) I still think that your idea is relevant mainly in modules that include some SQL code, where the ` ' ` character might occur frequently in SQL queries, but I will leave it to the op to tweak these measures, now that we have access to the line as a String variable.

Comment: @A.S.H. Thanks for the code. It works for what I want it for :)
A tweak I will probably implement is to judge is the position of the `'` character. i.e. whether you have single line comments or comments following your code. Which I guess depends on the way each person comments.